# Replace Strings Which Not Wrapped in a HTML Element with Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to overcome this conversion with Regex:

```
abc <a href="#abc">abc</a> abc
```

To:

```
lorem <a href="#abc">abc</a> lorem
```

My regex is:

```
preg_replace('/[^<="\']*.*(abc).*[^>="\']*/i','lorem',$text)
```

I tried many combinations, not help to convert.

What Regex does handle that?

Comment: Are you able to use `DOM`? you can easily query text nodes of root node with that.

Comment: No, I have to do it on backend side.

Comment: Can you use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php?

Comment: DOM is a standard that's not only a part of JS but most languages implement it. Check PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Wow I've never aware of that, thank you both! @TomášHübelbauer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(.*)(<a(.*?)\/a>)(.*)


group 1: abc
group :2 <a href="#abc">abc</a>
group 3: abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about regular expressions but you can try a php function

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

E.g:

```
echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");
```

the example above will replace "world" with peter

Comment: I need a Regex, not like that